# Enable member function overload depending on class template argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, class-method

This might be a stupid question but can I somehow use the requires clause without template arguments? I have the following case:

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:3,endLineNumber:10,positionColumn:3,positionLineNumber:10,selectionStartColumn:3,selectionStartLineNumber:10,startColumn:3,startLineNumber:10),source:%27%23include+%3Cconcepts%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T%3E%0Astruct+entity+%7B%0A++++requires+(std::same_as%3CT,+int%3E)+%0A++++auto+operator%3D(const+entity%26)+%7B+std::cout+%3C%3C+%22with+T+%3D%3D+int%22+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B+return+*this%3B+%7D%0A%0A++++auto+operator%3D(const+entity%26)+%7B+std::cout+%3C%3C+%22all+else%22+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B+return+*this%3B+%7D%0A%7D%3B%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g131,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Os%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+13.1+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:54.49790794979079,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+13.1%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+13.1+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:45.50209205020921,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
#include <concepts>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct entity {
    requires (std::same_as<T, int>) 
    auto operator=(const entity&) { std::cout << "with T == int" << std::endl; return *this; }

    auto operator=(const entity&) { std::cout << "all else" << std::endl; return *this; }
};
```

And I want to enable one overload based on the class template parameter, not a method template parameter. How do I do this inline and with concepts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to put the `requires`-clause after the *parameter-list* of the member function

```
template <typename T>
struct entity {
  auto operator=(const entity&)
    requires (std::same_as<T, int>) 
  { /* */ }

  auto operator=(const entity&) { /* */ }
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/oxccsxW8n)